# How can I store values inside JDT/ASTVisitor()?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have a code that detects the start position and length of invocation of a method in the source as follows.

I need to store those data outside the ASTVisitor(), but using final int, I got an error.

How can I store values inside ASTVisitor()?

```
public void setPositionFinder(String methodName) throws JavaModelException
{
    //findMethod(methodName);
    IType type = this.javaProject.findType(this.className);
    ICompilationUnit unit = type.getCompilationUnit();
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(unit);
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    CompilationUnit cunit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    //ASTNode root = parser.createAST(null);

    final String name = this.newMethodName;
    final int startPosition = -1;
    final int length = -1;

    cunit.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation methodInvocation)
        {
            String methodName = methodInvocation.getName().toString();
            System.out.println(methodName);
            if (methodName.equals(name))
            {
                // ERROR!
                startPosition = methodInvocation.getStartPosition();
                length = methodInvocation.getLength();
                System.out.printf("startPosition %d - Length %d", startPosition, length);       
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the *starPosition* and *length* variables as static member variables of the class. You can then access then from inside the ASTVisitor inner class. Changing the `setPositionFinder` method to static may also be preferred, so that it can be invoked in static way.